# android ViewModelProverders.of does not seem

Tags: android, kotlin

as you can see in the picture I want to write "" viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of (this) .get (Quiz Viewmodel :: class.java) "" but what should I do as a "" Proverder"" please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkmZL.png)

Comment: I'm glad you got an answer to your question, but could you please clean up your question? Please. The title is a cut off sentence, no capitalization, no spaces or paragraphs, has mistakes in it, it really looks sloppy. This is not the quality of content we want here on Stack Overflow. If you want us to put effort in our answers, put time into creating them for you, then please do the same with the question. It's a way to show respect to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewModelProviders` is deprecated use `ViewModelProvider` instead as shown below:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(Quiz Viewmodel :: class.java)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Please accept it as an answer if my answer helped you. You can check the tick mark below the voting button. Thanks in advance.